# Django how to conditionally update of field value based on other field value in a different model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-validation

```
class Details(models.Model):
    topicId = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices = TopicCategory.choices)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class ChoiceOptions(models.TextChoices):
    YES = 'YES', _('Yes')
    NO = 'NO', _('No')
    NA = 'NA', _('Na')


class MakeAChoice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topicId = models.ForeignKey(Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    myChoice = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices = ChoiceOptions.choices)




class DetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Details
        fields = ('topicId','name','group','status')

class MakeAChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = MakeAChoice
        fields = ('user','group','datetime_made',mychoice')
```

Here are my models & serializers for the MakeAChoice and Details class.
At present, I can make a choice and it gets saved when I fire a POST call. However, I want save my choice only if the value of the 'group' filed is 'Valid'.

How do I write the condition for this please? I need to get the field value in the other Model and verify it against a value and only if the condition is true, I want to update the choice in the current model.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow. If your question is where to put such validation, it can be in your serializer validate method.

Also I don't understand the relation between `MakeAChoice` and `Details` there's no DB relation between them. What exactly do you want to validate? If you have some code that you tried already, put it in question.

Comment: Hi Arman,

I edited the code. I call an api from where i make a choice from drop-down for a given topic. The topic again is selected from the drop down. When i make a choice and POST, it gets updated for the selected topic.

However i want to stop the selection from taking effect if the 'status' of the selected topic is not 'Valid'. 

Below are the two ways i could possibly use. 
1. Show only those topics which are valid in the choice api
2. When all topics are shown, validate it against the status 

In my case I have all topics appearing in choice api. How can i change this please?

Comment: If you want go the second way, why you don't add it as a validation to MakeAChoiceSerializer?